# What schemes can appear in the Origin header sent by a Fetch-compliant browser?

Tags: cors, same-origin-policy, url-scheme

I'm developing a CORS middleware library, and my ambition is to validate the user-allowed origins as much as possible in order to spare my users dysfunctional CORS configurations.

Browsers [byte-serialize](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#byte-serializing-a-request-origin) the issuing [Web origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) of a cross-origin request and then use the result as the value of the [`Origin` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) that they automatically attach to the request.

**What schemes can appear in the `Origin` header (sent by a Fetch-compliant browser)?** What is the cardinality of the set of such schemes?

`http` and `https` are in that set; that much is clear. Also, I know that [byte-serializing an opaque origin](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#ascii-serialisation-of-an-origin) (e.g. an origin whose scheme is `data`) results in `null`. But can the `Origin` header contain schemes other than `http` and `https`? The [Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) (the de facto CORS specification, among other things) doesn't seem to place a restriction on that...

Comment: Interesting question! You probably already know this, but Origin by definition [includes scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin). I think the main question here is what schemes can run JavaScript, specifically run fetch or an xhr request, and invoke CORS in a browser context? I can't think of anything else besides http/https on face value, but I don't understand schemes very well so I can't really answer this. Good luck!

Comment: How does this play into your middleware though? In most CORS middleware I've seen, the middleware user will specify an array of origins. Are you wanting to restrict the scheme to some predefined pattern? It probably makes more sense to allow every scheme.

Comment: @Nathan Thanks! I hope sideshowbarker or one of the Fetch-standard people will see this question and be able to give me a definite answer.

Comment: (We posted comments at the same time, so want to make sure you didn't miss my last one. Along with those questions, I'm curious what language/framework you're using, though that's not particularly relevant)

Comment: @Nathan Yes, if I can, I'd like to restrict the schemes of the origins specified in the config. That way, if the user attempts to allow `httpx://example.com`, I can fail at execution (assuming `httpx` is not a scheme that can appear in the `Origin` header, of course).

Comment: @Nathan I'm implementing this in Go. Here is a preview: https://twitter.com/jub0bs/status/1585696295867465728

Comment: Understood, and I'm all for creating secure-by-default middleware, seems like a cool project! From my understanding, all schemes are allowed, and it's probably very difficult to exhaustively list them. [This article](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-works) states `The most commonly used protocols are http://, https://, ftp://, and mailto://.`

Honestly, I think enforcing a specific scheme is a bad idea, even if you fail at compile time instead of runtime.

Comment: @Nathan Of course, if all schemes are fair game, this is a fool's errand. But one may hope!

Comment: I've designed a fair amount of security-related libraries, and you usually want secure-by-default but having expressive configuration (that needs to be explicitly specified) for edge conditions which you frankly won't be able to anticipate. You may want to allow the standard origins by default (some scheme argument that's a union of string literal types if Go supports that?), and provide an escape hatch where anyone can say "I know what I'm doing. Use `foo://` as the scheme". :)

Comment: In typescript, I'd do something like `constructOrigin(scheme: "http" | "https" | "ftp" | "mailto" | {customScheme: string}, ...)`

Comment: Even if certain schemes are disallowed by the spec (which I doubt at this point), there's a huge variety of browsers and javascript execution contexts that may not follow the spec to the letter. Flexibility is good.

Comment: @Nathan That's not a bad idea, actually! I've already got a system of escape hatches in place (provided by a namespace/package called `risky`). I could allow only `http` and `https` by default, and provide an option to enable people to use more exotic schemes. Thanks!

Comment: np! Here's a [list of URI schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes), including the official list registered with IANA, as well as unoffical-but-common schemes. (something else to consider is making "http", as opposed to "https", have some sort of riskiness associated with it in the middleware's API, or maybe a runtime warning?)

Comment: @Nathan Yes, I'm planning to disable `http` by default, as it is dangerous in an origin allowed for CORS. FYI, see the section entitled _Breaking HTTPS_ in https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties. Alternatively, https://twitter.com/jub0bs/status/1352160391032401923/photo/1.

Comment: I don’t really have a useful comment to add — so I’m mostly just commenting to ack this. I can’t cite a specific part of any spec for an authoritative answer on this — but from reasoning about it, I can’t imagine a scenario where an origin in browsers is every going to be something with a scheme other than http or https, or else something that gets serialized to null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can see "`ftp`" from legacy clients, FTP was never much tested before it got removed. And in https://github.com/fedidcg/FedCM/issues/320#issuecomment-1274306658 I floated the idea of an `about:browser` value, which would give you "`about`". As noted by evilpie extensions might give you "`moz-extension`" or "`chrome-extension`". Apart from that just "`http`" and "`https`".

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this thoughtful answer, Anne! I really appreciate it.

Comment: It might be useful to note that browser extensions will sometimes trigger requests with schemes like `moz-extension` or `chrome-extension`.

Comment: @evilpie Hadn’t thought about that but yeah, it does seem like in the extension case, browsers do end up setting the Origin value to something with a `chrome-extension` (or sometimes `chrome`?) or whatever scheme.

Comment: @evilpie Ah you're wrecking my world! Would you write a complementary answer?